# Does Google Analytics track the same goal multiple times per visit?

Tags: google-analytics

I've set up Google Analytics and three goals. But it seems like each goal is converted only once per visit. Is it possible to convert the same goals several times? I use an event to convert the goal and it is like a "wrote a post".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. It won't. Check out this [helpful answer](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en) from the Google Analytics Help center.
[image]

> GA will track any Goal Conversion once per visit. If you have 2 Goals
>   set-up, one visitor during the same session can convert on both goals,
>   and GA will count both conversions. It won't count repeat goal
>   conversions per session (so if someone reaches your Thank You page for
>   a Goal Conversion, and then goes to refresh the page 5 times, GA won't
>   count 6 Goal Conversions, it will only count 1 / the "unique
>   pageview").

There's no way around this. However, since you're tracking these events, you'll still have the raw event numbers in your event tracking report.

Comment: For those of you in the future.. like myself... which is currently my present that link no longer works, it just redirects.

I did however find in the docs where it states this, https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en

Comment: If a user visits `example.com/thankyouforpurchasing` once today, and once again in two days (in the same browser), will it count for 2 goal conversions?  (I guess it's not the same "visit" anymore?) @Yahel

Comment: That will be 2 sessions.

Comment: What about e-commerce tracking? Can you have two transactions in one session?

Comment: @SilverRingvee, yes transactions register multiple times in the same sessions, different to goal tracking. Good summary of those here compared to adwords conversion tracking as well: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en

Comment: @captainrad - added your link to Answer. Thanks for link!